# Regex with percentage and int

Tags: regex

Hy, just a quick one here, does anyone know a good regular expression for a percentage and another number? I want to use it in a XML Schema..

Should Match:

```
-1
100.00
20.00
20.0
10.0
20
99.0
66.4
0.00
```

So it should match a percentage OR -1

My approach doesnt work...

```
([/-1]{1}|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,2})
```

Thanks!

Comment: If I get you right, you need `-1|[0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?|100(\.00)?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(-1\n|\b(100|\d{1,2})(\n|(\.\d{1,2})))
```

Explanation:

```
(-1\n|                  // when not percentage OR ...
     \b                 // word boundary - must not be other symbols in front 
       (100|            // when integer part is equal to 100 OR ...
           \d{1,2}      // when integer part is number between 0 and 99
       )                // then after integer part must follow:
       (\n|             // new line symbol OR ...
           (\.\d{1,2})  // dot symbol AND fractional part composed of 0 and 99
       )
)
```

Comment: That'll match `999.99`.

Comment: fixed solution - now avoids such cases

Answer (score 1):

For regular expressions I usually use and suggest [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) as a reference.

That being said if I understand what you are trying to do this would work for you:

`/(?=\s+|^)(?:-1|100(?:\.0+)?|\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,})?)(?=\s+)/gm`

This would match strings that have nothing or white-spaces before and after 

`(?=\s+|^) content (?=\s+)`

You can optionally alter that to `^(?: content)$` if you want each number to be the only thing on each line.

Where content is any of:

- -1 ( `-1` )
- 100 optionally folowed by "." and 1 or more 0s ( `100(?:\.0+)?` )
- 1 or 2 digits optionally followed by "." and 1 or more decimals ( `\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,})?` )

You could alter the ending of `{1,}` to `{1,X}` where X is the max number of decimals you want to match.

For matching results check [RegExr](http://regexr.com/3fsv3)

Comment: Your regex matches `1212.123` or `abc1212.123xyz`

Comment: @Toto Thanks for your comment! I think I resolved the issue. Let me know if you find some other issue with the new regex :)

Comment: XSD Schema is not quite compatible with JavaScript regex flavor. Your regex won't work there.

Comment: @Toto Edited again. This should resolve the 2nd issue as well.